# Python Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to get a simple host/client transfer working. I followed a tutorial, and the server goes up without problems, but when the client tries to connect it returns "Connection reset by peer." I honstly don't know where the error is.

```
class genSocket:

def __init__(self, sock=None):
    if sock is None:
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    else:
        self.sock = sock

def bind(self, ip, port):
    self.sock.bind((ip, port))

def listen(self, maxcon):
    self.sock.listen(maxcon)
    while True:
        self.sock.accept()

def accept(self):
    self.sock.accept()
    while True:
        print (self.recieve())

def connect(self, host, port):
    self.sock.connect((host, port))

def send(self, msg, type):
    totalsent = 0
    prefix = str(type) + str(len(msg)).rjust(5, '0')
    print prefix
    while totalsent < 6:
        sent = self.sock.send(prefix)
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Connection broken!")

    print "sent prefix"

    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < len(msg):
        sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("Connection broken!")
        totalsent = + sent

def recieve(self):
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < 6:
        prefix = self.sock.recv(6)
        if prefix == '':
            raise RuntimeError("Connection broken!")
        prefix.append(prefix)
        bytes_recd = + len(prefix)

    print "recieved prefix"

    chunks = []
    msglen = prefix[1:]
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < msglen:
        chunk = self.sock.recv(min(msglen - bytes_recd, 2048))
        if chunk == '':
            raise RuntimeError("Connection broken!")
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_recd = + len(chunk)
    return ''.join(chunks)
```

Answer (score 0):

`socket.accept()` will return a *new* socket object that you need to use for sending and receiving. Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept).

e.g.:

```
def accept(self):
    conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
    while True:
        print (self.recieve(conn))
```

and change `self.recieve()` to use the new socket.

Also, this implementation is not going to accept() any new client while it's serving the first, but you can specify a greater than zero `maxcon` value for the `listen()` call.

This would make any new client (up to `maxcon` value) connect successfully and then wait in line waited to be served, but this implementation looks like it's going to just quit when the client stops the connection (I didn't check carefully, though :) ) so it would be better to give a zero backlog value to `listen()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
newsock, clientaddr = oldsock.accept()
while True:
    print newsock.recv(100), "from", clientaddr[0], "on port", clientaddr[1]
```

When OS receives a connection on listened port OS switches the port to new free port.
In that way you can continue listening to your port for new connections while working with one that just arrived.
socket.accept() will wait until that connection comes, then it will return you a new socket bound to the new port, and a tuple(address, port), where address is an IP of the client and port the new port which OS gave internally.
So, if you mean to disassociate your accept() method from receive(), you will have to save that new socket in some attribute.
Or pass it as an argument as garph0 said.

When client breaks a connection recv() will throw an error, as far as I remember. Then you call newsock.close(), or you call it when you wish to close the door in the client's nose. Then you calmly continue to wait for new one.

Comment: There is no _port_ change when you accept a connection on the server, otherwise how would a server be able to accept multiple connections. Also, socket.accept() returns a tuple (socket, remote_address), not (socket, port).

Comment: @garph0 Please learn something before blurting out, and pay attention to what people are writing. Yes, there is a port change. Original port is the same, but accepted connection is, well, accepted on another port. That's why you can continue to listen for incoming connections on your port while "talking" to a client on accepted one. And, yes, accept() returns a tuple, but that tuple contains a new socket and another tuple which consists of an address of  the client in the form(IP, PORT) where PORT is the port on which the incoming connection is using and IP the IP of the connected client.

Comment: @graph0 If I was unclear before, be so good and edit my post after one good reading about sockets, or you may consider taking a Computer Networks course. Cheers!

Comment: @garph0 Sorry I misspelled your username.

Comment: The PORT will not change when accepting the connection, but yes, you'll get a new SOCKET. You may want to find out what a [PORT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) is and what a [SOCKET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) is.

Comment: @garph0, Hey, baby, you're talking to a man who wrote a multiconnection HTTP server in Python for high loads and heavy traffic, and I can't even remember how many server-client applications. I will not argue any more. Anyone here wishing to try what I am talking about, and knowing something about sockets will se who is right and who is wrong. I see that you are a copy-paste and adapt man without trying to really understand what is going on in the background. If you wish to answer me, please try your own example first, and put print address after conn, address = sock.accept() to see new port.

Comment: sure you did. And yet you don't know the difference between a socket object and a port. Or between the local address and the remote one. Go figure.

Comment: Oh, now you would like to wiggle out by accusing me about not knowing difference between local and remote address.
Firstly by stating that I don't know a difference between socket and a port.
Thank you very much for making me laugh.
I see you didn't try to print the *complete* remote address of the incoming client to see it's remote port.
Did you ever read anything about TCP/IP stack and its implementation?Did no one explained to you how OS kernel handles sockets?
Anyway, why am I loosing my time here, it's obvious you like to think that you're right even when you're wrong.
So, enjoy yourself!

Comment: I actually am having some kind of fun. Not sure you would understand why, though :-P Take care.

Comment: :-P right back at you! If you being stubborn makes you happy, then I am having some fun too! LMAO